# CAPTCHA not displaying on "Human verification"

Tags: support, bug, captcha

I'm not able to answer a question on Stack Overflow because the *Human Verification* page is showing up but without any CAPTCHA. I found many questions relating this but without a solution that worked for me. I guess this has something to do with my No-Script settings (Firefox plug-in). I selected "Temporarily allow all this page" several times but without success. I don't know of any proxy related restrictions on my internet connection but anyhow I there were some, I couldn't change them. Does this mean I can't pass the "Human verification"?

[image: Human Verification - Are you a human being?]

[image: Chrome console with XHR time out]

Comment: Can you post screenshot of what you see? Can you temporarily disable the plugin or try from different browser?

Comment: The same in here, usually it works (the big checkbox is loaded), but now I've refreshed and re-tried few times and no luck. Could be just my connection or something.

Comment: I just had the same problem without No-Script plugin, using Safari with only AdBlock but it's disabled on SE and should block Google's ReCaptcha either way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know exactly how NoScript works, but there might be some setting for blocking/allowing third-party scripts. The reCAPTCHA script gets loaded from `http://www.google.com/recaptcha/...`.

Also, if you disable JavaScript altogether (in Firefox, not NoScript), the `<noscript>` version of the Captcha page should get displayed, which doesn't require JavaScript at all.

Comment: In the beginning, I tried it with Java Script completely disabled. Then, I also allowed all from `google.com`.

Comment: Did you disable JavaScript in NoScript or in Firefox itself? I think it makes a difference. Also, try visiting http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LdchgIAAAAAAJwGpIzRQSOFaO0pU6s44Xt8aTwc. If you can't see the image there either, your problem isn't related to JavaScript.

Comment: JavaScript is enabled in Firefox settings. The CAPTCHA on http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LdchgIAAAAAAJwGpIzRQSOFaO0pU6s44Xt8aTwc shows up.

Comment: Then try disabling it in Firefox. That should display the `<noscript>` version.

Comment: Disabling NoScript and disabling JavaScript in Firefox settings worked. A related but different problem is that without JavaScript, I can't comment. ;) Thank you!

Comment: Well, in any case, this is a workaround. With NoScript disabled and JavaScript enabled, it *should* work.

Comment: Yes, and it also works with disabled JavaScript. But I consider the fact that my browser behaves different with JavaScript disabled via Firefox settings compared to JavaScript disabled via NoScript as a bug (or at least unexpected behavior) of NoScript and not Stack Overflow.

Comment: But in China we don't have Google. So how can I solve this problem

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this problem with Firefox 89.0. All I had to do was click the "X" on the upper right of the "Human verification" popup, and then the "I'm not a robot" checkbox suddenly appeared.

But when I clicked on the "I'm not a robot" checkbox, I got an "An error occurred submitting the captcha" message. I had to close the popup, click "Post your question" again, click on the "X" on the upper right of the "Human verification" popup again, and click on the "I'm not a robot" checkbox again, and then it worked.

[image]

Comment: They check how much you really want to post that question.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue in Firefox. It was casued by having tracking protection turned on. I was able to fix it by going to "Preferences" and then to "Privacy and Security" And temporarily disabling "Tracking Protection"