# "Images with street signs" CAPTCHA impossible to solve

Tags: bug, captcha

I just got challenged (over on [English Language](https://english.stackexchange.com/)) by the new "Mark all images with street signs" CAPTCHA.

I must have tried a dozen times to solve it by checking all images that had street signs, but I never succeeded.

Of note is a text input field without instructions of what to enter there. I suspect that is the problem: It is expecting input, but doesn't tell me what to input.

It's either broken or I am missing something.

I am using Chrome on an iPhone in "full site" mode.

Comment: Nice try, robot.

Comment: In all seriousness, I don't hit captcha's all that often on SE, but the ones I do hit are usually absolutely, positively maddening. You'd think we'd have less annoying captchas by now.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot or so?

Comment: I got Captcha there too, but only with a checkbox, no further step.

Comment: Might be same cause as here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145051/captcha-not-displaying-on-human-verification

Comment: For what it's worth, I've never successfully solved one of the CAPTCHAs presented when you try to search without logging in.

Comment: @ShadowWizard You only get further verification steps when Google cannot confirm that you are not a robot.

Comment: What happened to that fancy new captcha thing, where you just click the checkbox and be done?

Comment: @Undo http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267214/images-with-street-signs-captcha-impossible-to-solve?noredirect=1#comment866860_267214.

Comment: Related: [Picture captcha are impossible to answer as pictures are not discernable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293667/picture-captcha-are-impossible-to-answer-as-pictures-are-not-discernable)

Comment: @cool agreed some were very hard to distinguish, but even when 9 were clear, and I ticked the correct images, it still failed to pass.

Comment: @PatrickHofman sorry, no screenshot.

Comment: @Undo Some People allow Google to track their gps data, Position, search Terms, history and what not. For those People, Google can "tell" they are human, thus only a Checkbox. Everybody with a Minimum of privacy Settings has to solve the Picture captchas.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the captcha service is offered by Google, not by SE. Any issues with it should be directed at the servicedesk of Google. There is nothing to fix for SE.

Comment: @rene: If there's a high-level problem with the basic usability of the CAPTCHA chosen, SE *can* decide to just get a different provider. That is an option.

Comment: @NathanTuggy sure, but that is not what is asked here. This reports a bug that is now in the wrong issue-tracker ...

Comment: @rene it's definitively a bug. SE can't fix the bug per se because it isn't their code. But SE can make the bug go away by using a provider that doesn't have a buggy CAPTCHA. So, being "fixable", it's on-topic.

Comment: I'm not going into the philosophical debate where a bug ends and a feature requests start. Maybe I shouldn't take questions literally. Oh well.

Answer (score 13):

Here's a screenshot of the one I currently can't pass

Now the other thing is, if you're supposed to select images, what's with the text box below. There are no instructions on what to enter there.

[image: streetsigns reCaptcha]

Comment: Whenever I get the "street sign" captcha, i can't solve it either. Every Other captcha works nice, but this one always Fails. (And I tried it hundrets of times by now.)

Comment: For the TextBox: Once you solved the captcha, a code will appear. You then have to copy&paste that code into the TextBox. (Instructions appear as well when captcha is solved)

Comment: @dognose I always fail at the street signs too. 
 I think that's because my opinion of what a street sign is differs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_name_sign
"A street name sign is a type of traffic sign used to identify named roads, generally those that do not qualify as expressways or highways. Street name signs are most often found posted at intersections, and are usually in perpendicularly oriented pairs identifying each of the crossing streets."

Comment: the trick is to select everything that's a speed, warning or a street name. and somehow assume that whoever did the tests before didn't select shop name signs etc.

it's really a waste of time and gone really bad lately a captcha is a pretty bad bad when your false positive rate is over 50%+

it's really hard with some pictures where the picture itself is so blurry.

what sucks more is that.. if it's 5 pixels into the other box, should you select that too? or not?

Comment: In the text, you're supposed to type "Please, I'm not a robot. I promise. Please let me pass." Everybody knows that.